# In Dynamics 365, how do I support preview of attachments (Excel, Word, PDF) instead of viewing them after downloading

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

In Dynamics 365, how do I support preview of attachments (Excel, Word, PDF) instead of viewing them after downloading.

For example, after clicking on a PDF file in the timeline, a preview window appears

[image]